# What's the performance difference between having state in place and using a function to get state?

Tags: javascript

Just for an example, let's see we have three event listeners, `mousemove`, `keydown`, `keyup`. We want to record the `space` key, and the current mouse position.

```
import getState from "../state";

  //version one, the variable is in place and gets mutated if changes
let spacePressed = false;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (x, y) => {
  if (spacePressed) doSomethingWithMousePos(x, y);
});
  //version two, the variable is in a state outside

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (x, y) => {
  const { spacePressed } = getState();

  if (spacePressed) doSomethingWithMousePos(x, y);
});

//...

window.addEventListener("keydown", functionWhichSetsSpacePressed);
window.addEventListener("keyup", functionWhichSetsSpacePressed);
```

Just to clarify it's not React or Redux related. The example is good, because `mousemove` happens quite often, so even small performance difference matters. So what's the difference between having the state in place, and the function just needs to read it, and having the state in an outside file, where the function delivers the state itself? (something like this:

```
const state = {};
export const getState = () => state;
```

)

Comment: Calling a function is slower than just reading a variable.

Comment: I believe if there's any performance difference - it's almost nothing and shouldn't bother.

Comment: If you're worried about the fact that `mousemove` events occur frequently, you should probably debounce it so don't execute on every tiny movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to mention - is that optimizing those things in front-end javascript is nearly useless, because main bottleneck here is DOM operations, and DOM rendering.
But if you're really interested, I won't answer what's faster and what's slower, I will post a way to measure those things easily using `benchmark.js`.

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite();

const state = {};
const getState = () => state;

// add tests
suite.add('Get State', function() {
  getState()['foo'] = 'bar';
})
.add('Read state', function() {
  state.foo = 'bar';
}).on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
}).run({'async': true});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.4/benchmark.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```